# How concatenate strings with a newline

Tags: bash, newline

I want to string concatenation two given strings line1 and line2 and entering a newline between them. Any idea please?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
enter='\n'
lines=$line1$enter$line2
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @karakfa Double quoting won't help.

Comment: try  `v=1; u=2; nl=$'\n'; echo $v$nl$u` vs `echo "$v$nl$u"`

Comment: Double quotes aren't required in assignments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$'...'` to have the shell interpret escape sequences.

```
enter=$'\n'
lines=$line1$enter$line2
```

You can also put a newline directly inside double quotes:

```
lines="$line1
$line2"
```

Or use `printf`:

```
printf -v lines '%s\n%s' "$line1" "$line2"
```